# Graph GET /places API returns an ID different than what is in /users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$top=2&$select=ID,DisplayName,emailAddress
```

Returns

```
{
  "emailAddress": "ConferenceRoom022-noTZ@ZZZ.onmicrosoft.com",
  "displayName": "Conference Room 022-noTZ",
  "id": "4b75be13-0d74-42cb-88b3-498cd26fda21",
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.room"
}
```

But

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq 'ConferenceRoom022-noTZ@ZZZ.onmicrosoft.com'&$select=ID,DisplayName,mail
```

returns a totally different ID

```
  {
     "@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v2/7173d778-cc47-456b-b558-a81a538ad021/directoryObjects/80012172-191d-4a5c-af1d-51a4e1dd8430/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
     "displayName":"Conference Room 022-noTZ",
     "mail":"ConferenceRoom022-noTZ@fmsystemsdev.onmicrosoft.com",
     "id":"80012172-191d-4a5c-af1d-51a4e1dd8430"
  }
```

This means I can't use /places to build a lookup of ID to EMail so when processing WebHook notifications the ID in the WebHook does not match the Places values.  The Places API (3,000+ entries) is much faster than pulling all /users (30,000+).

Comment: The User and Place are different resources and are bound to have different ids. Please explain your scenario like what resource you receive webhook notifications for and what you are trying to achieve so that you can get better precise help.

Comment: #1) WebHook calendar change provides the User ID of the Resource.  I need the Resource e-mail address.  Getting /Place records is very fast and provides the e-mail addresses but no matching ID. /User to get the e-mail address takes a separate /User call for each Resource.  #2) Issue Subscription start requests for 1000's of resources given the e-mail address of each Resource, need the IDs.  /User 1000's of times for each Resource slow.  /User to pull all records can be faster but not if 10,000's users and no OData filter on Resources.  /Place is quick but the IDs returned are useless.